# Session security and ASP.NET Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, security

I'm starting to use ASP.NET Ajax.  Following [Eric Pascarello's](http://weblogs.asp.net/rhurlbut/archive/2006/02/16/438365.aspx) recommendations, I always operate under the assumption that anything can come from the client side (including fake requests).

One matter which I have a hard time accounting for is user authentication.  Since we use .NET's built-in session state management mechanism, I'm a bit ignorant of what security risks exist with the webservices.

What do I need to do to be certain that the user is who he says he is (to a reasonable enough probability)?  Is using

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you make sure the Session object is available in your method.  If you want to make sure they are authenticated then configure it in your web.config

```
<location path="MyService.asmx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```